# Sharpening up the Clarity of a FedEx Label

Tags: c#, memorystream, bitmapimage

I have been trying to get this to work with no solution in site. I am printing out a FedEx label to an invoice. When I read the bytes of the label and print it out, the clarity is all fuzzy in the lines and text. I tried saving the file and reading it as well, but the same thing, the printing out is all fuzzy. When I view the image at 100% it's clear.

I don't have this problem with Stamps.com. Here I read the label, it's the same size as FedEx and it prints out clear as day. So it's something else I am missing. Any thoughts on this?

Here is the code I am using:

```
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(packageDetail.Label.Parts[0].Image);
                        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(ms);

                        img.SetResolution(mRes, mRes);

                        Bitmap tmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);
                        tmp.SetResolution(mRes, mRes);

                        Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(tmp);
                        gr.DrawImageUnscaled(img, 0, 0);

                        img.Save(ShipInfo[5].ToString() + ShipInfo[4].ToString() + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
                        img.Dispose();
                        gr.Dispose();
```

Comment: *Enhance...* Seriously thought, where are you getting the file? Is it a high resolution file?

Comment: Without the data file, and without values for `mRes`, it's going to be difficult to deduce much of anything here.

Comment: It looks like it's 96dpi. It's coming from FedEx from their API. mRes I have set to 203f

Comment: Though I will say, you should consider [`using` statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) instead of `Dispose` calls.

Comment: You'll need to find a better bitmap.  The one you have is only suitable for display on a monitor.  A printer has a resolution of 600 dpi so every single pixel in the bitmap turns into a 6x6 blob of ink on paper.  You need really long arms to make *that* look good.

Comment: Their API must support a higher resolution somewhere.

Comment: Okay thanks. You're all right. The images look fine on screen, however FedEx label is 96 dpi while USPS is 200dpi so I need to see how I can get a bigger version.